# How can I make my HorizontalBarChart scrollable?

Tags: android, android-studio, mpandroidchart

Currently trying to implement a HorizontalBarChart using MPAndroidChart. However, there are too many bars and they won't all fit on the screen. HorizontalBarChart will scroll only if I zoom in, but will never go past what was already on the screen. Not sure if this is an XML problem (I have the HorizontalBarChart in a Relative Layout, tried ScrollView but didn't work) or if there's already an implementation like chart.enableScroll() (which I have tried, and it doesn't work).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use `chart.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(10)` to control the number of entries that should be visible at once. If the chart contains more values, it will automatically allow scrolling.

More here: https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Modifying-the-Viewport

Comment: Wow, PhilJay himself! Thank you! I used setVisibleYRangeMaximum instead (for some reason X did nothing - maybe because it was a HorizontalBarChart, but that fixed it

Comment: Hi Squeegene, Could you please help me I want to show only 4 horizontal bars then it will scroll. But I am not able to do the same.

Comment: Hi, this setVisibleXRangeMaximum method now take floating values. Can someone guide me to achieve this in latest version of MPAndroidChart?

Comment: [IMPORTANT] use this solution after setData

Comment: @AliZarei your comment was vital, thank you.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @AliZarei. Your comment was a cherry on top of it.

Answer (score 4):

```
chart.setData(...); // first set data
// now modify viewport
chart.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(5); // allow 5 values to be displayed
chart.moveViewToX(1);// set the left edge of the chart to x-index 1
```

You can use above way